# ios / swift - I can't append tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to get data from the server and display it as a TableView. 
Getting the data was successful. However, the data works well only in the "getDur1Data ()" function by append to the TableList, which is not work in the class...

so I don't know why TableView.count == 0 in there(I appended "listSeparated" in "TableList" before...)

also I hope to know why "print("row value (row)")" is output before "print(self.Table.cout)" in getDur1Data()

```
class CustomPortController : UITableViewController {
    var TableList = Array<CustomPortVO>()
    var listSeparated = CustomPortVO()

    func getDur1Data(){
    …
          self.TableList.append(self.listSeparated)
          print(self.TableList.count) //in here, it works well so output is "1", "2", "3"..
   }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getDur1Data()
    }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let row  = self.TableList.count
        print("row value \(row)") // in here, "row value 0" is output three times
        return row
    }
}
```

**Edited - rewrite all code**

```
class CustomPortController : UITableViewController {
    var TableList = Array<CustomPortVO>()
    var listSeparated = CustomPortVO()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.getDur1Data()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let row  = self.TableList.count
        print("row value \(row)")
        return row

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row = self.TableList[indexPath.row]

//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell1") as! UITableViewCell
//        NSLog("result=\(row.title), row index=\(indexPath.row)");

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell1") as! CustomPortTableViewCell
        cell.indexNum?.text = "\(row.indexNum!)"
        cell.nameOfStyle?.text = row.title
        cell.percentage?.text = row.rating
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let row = self.TableList[indexPath.row]
//        NSLog("result=\(row.title), row index=\(indexPath.row)");
        /*
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell1") as! CustomPortTableViewCell
        cell.indexNum?.text = "\(row.indexNum!)"
        cell.nameOfStyle?.text = row.title
        cell.percentage?.text = row.rating*/

    }



    func getDur1Data(){
        let url1:String  = "private url, sorry :)"
        let url1Enc = URL(string: url1)
        if let _url = url1Enc{
            var request = URLRequest(url: _url)
            request.httpMethod = "get"

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
                guard error == nil && data != nil else{
                    if let err = error{
                        print(err.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    return
                }

                if let _data = data{
                    if let strData = NSString(data: _data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
                        let str = String(strData)

                        var separatedData = str.split(separator: "=")
                        for i in 1...3{
                            separatedData[i*4].removeFirst()
                            var index = separatedData[i*4].index(of:"\"")!
                            separatedData[i*4] = separatedData[i*4][..<index]
                            separatedData[i*4+1].removeFirst()
                            index = separatedData[i*4+1].index(of:"\"")!
                            separatedData[i*4+1] = separatedData[i*4+1][..<index]
                            print("\(separatedData[i*4])\n");
                            print("\(separatedData[i*4+1])\n")
                        }

                        for row in 1...3{
                            self.listSeparated.indexNum = row
                            self.listSeparated.rating = String(separatedData[row*4 + 1])
                            self.listSeparated.title = String(separatedData[row*4])
                            print(self.listSeparated.indexNum!)
                            print(self.listSeparated.rating!)
                            print(self.listSeparated.title!)
                            self.TableList.append(self.listSeparated)

                            print(self.TableList.count)
                            print(self.TableList[row-1])
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        }

                    }

                }else{
                    print("data nil")
                }
            }
            task.resume()

        }


    }
}
```

when I build this proj, first time I can't see any table cell. But after coming back to Tableview I can see 3 table cell which have same data like this

> 1 abcd 1234
>   1 abcd 1234
>   1 abcd 1234

Comment: What order do you see the print output? The one from getDur1Data first then the one in numberOfRows? If so it’ll help to see more of your code (specifically any code to do with listSeparated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `self.tableView.reloadData()`after your array is updated from the request.

Also, when fetching data for the table you have to use `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)  I tried what you answered but sadly it didnt work too.

Comment: post your full  self.getDur1Data(), viewDidLoad (or viewWillAppear if moved already)

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomPortController : UITableViewController {
    var tableList = [CustomPortVO]()
    var listSeparated = CustomPortVO()

    func getDur1Data(){
    …
          self.tableList.append(self.listSeparated)
          print(self.TableList.count)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.getDur1Data()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let row  = self.tableList.count
        print("row value \(row)") 
        return row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow Extract-Transform-Load (ETL) pattern.

So given a data source in some kind of form like XML, JSON or whatever.

> 1. **E**xtract every relevant information from it.

You have done this in a block starting with `if let _data = data{`

> 2. **T**ransform it into the model used by the tableView.

In this part. I think you need to create new object of `CustomPortV0`
rather than changing attributes of an already existing one like you did in `self.listSeparated.rating = ...`.

Because `CustomPortV0` is defined as a class and a class is reference type not value type. So no matter how much you append to tableView's model they will just refer to only one instance of `CustomPortV0`.
You need to create new instance of `CustomPortV0` then append that new instance to tableView's model (TableList).

> 3. **L**oad the model to the tableView so it can be shown.

This part is missing in your code.
You can use `tableView.reloadData()`to display them all at once or using `tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation)` to display specific row(s)

Hope this helps.

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load